# Column id is not unique

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have read and know that if column id (primary key) is not unique, it will yield above error.
But it is not my case as far as I know.

I created a class called Databasehandler and lots of functions (with 5 table) in it. then I create other classes/activities that uses functions in DBH.

I have added two report sections, one is current and the other one is old reports.

Now when ever I want to use a function it returns "column id is not unique (code 19)" error.

here is a part of my code.

I am really confused and appreciate any help.

```
package com.amirkh.taghzie;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataBaseHand extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Taghziemanager";
    private static final String TABALE_BMI = "bmitable";
    private static final String TABALE_OLDREPORT = "oldreport";
    private static final String TABALE_WATER = "water";
    private static final String TABALE_OLDWATER = "oldwater";
    private static final String TABALE_INTAKECAL = "intakecal";
    private static final String KEY_CALORIENEED = "neededcalorie";
    private static final String TABALE_FOODS = "foods";
    private static final String TABALE_DAILY = "daily";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ROID = "roid";
    private static final String KEY_DATEE = "datee";
    private static final String KEY_IDC = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_FOODNAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_UNITS = "units";
    private static final String KEY_CALORIE = "calorie";
    private static final String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";
    private static final String KEY_WATER = "waterdaily";
    private static final String KEY_BMI = "bmidata";
    private static final String KEY_FOODUNIT = "foodunit";
    private static final String KEY_TOTALCALORIE = "totalcalorie";
    private static String wa = "0";   
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABALE_BMI + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_BMI + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_TOTALCALORIE + " TEXT);");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABALE_INTAKECAL + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_CALORIENEED + " TEXT);");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO intakecal VALUES ('1','2500');");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABALE_WATER + " (" + KEY_ID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_WATER + " TEXT);");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO water VALUES ('1','0');");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABALE_DAILY + " ("
                + KEY_IDC + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_FOODNAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_FOODUNIT + " TEXT, " + KEY_ROID + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATEE
                + " TEXT );");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABALE_FOODS + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_FOODNAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_COMMENT + " TEXT, " + KEY_CALORIE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_FOODUNIT + " TEXT);");
```

and here is a function:

```
    public List<Foods> getfoodlist() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABALE_FOODS, null);
        List<Foods> fl = new ArrayList<Foods>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Foods food = new Foods("", "", "", "");
                food.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                food.setNamee(cursor.getString(1));
                food.setCommeent(cursor.getString(2));
                food.setCalor(cursor.getString(3));
                food.setUnit(cursor.getString(4));
                fl.add(food);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return fl;

    }
```

and an activity that I use function:

```
 public class Report extends ActionBarActivity {
    DataBaseHand dbh = new DataBaseHand(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);
        Button btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreportback);
            dbh.ResetDataBase();

        Button btnoldreport=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreportyesterday);
        Button btnreport=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreportreport);
        List<EatenFood> fl = dbh.GetEatenlist();
```

I got error on fl. (last line) or any other function that uses my database.

Any help will be appreciated, code itself is too long if you need more info please tell me.

EDIT:

Inputs are taken from user for all 5 tables i.e:

```
     public void addCalorie(String calorieNeeded) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABALE_INTAKECAL);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABALE_INTAKECAL + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_CALORIENEED + " TEXT);");

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(KEY_CALORIENEED, calorieNeeded);
        db.insert(TABALE_INTAKECAL, null, content);
            }
```

EDIT 2:
changed all TEXT PRIMARY KEY to INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (since they are auto increment) still no luck

EDIT 3: Logcat:

```
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amirkh.taghzie/com.amirkh.taghzie.Foodlist}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: PRIMARY KEY must be unique (code 19)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:727)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1665)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at com.amirkh.taghzie.DataBaseHand.onCreate(DataBaseHand.java:84)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at com.amirkh.taghzie.DataBaseHand.getfoodlist(DataBaseHand.java:135)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at com.amirkh.taghzie.Foodlist.onCreate(Foodlist.java:44)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
 08-21 11:56:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(2987):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: "not unique" errors come from inserts/updates and you've only shown a select. Please include the relevant code and stacktrace.

Comment: thanks. I have added an input function. it is weird error since it works before I add last activity(report)

Comment: The problem is in `DataBaseHand.onCreate()` which you have not shown.

Comment: added to first block code at the end.by the way thanks for help

Comment: ... the problematic `execSQL()` is on row 84 and now you've only posted something like up to row 63.

Comment: row 84 is  db.execSQL("INSERT INTO water VALUES ('1','0');"); i just have deleted comments and empty lines

Comment: it worked! thanks but I wonder: I have worked 6 days with the same code why it suddenly become an error? ps: use answer so I can choose it as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace says you're attempting to insert a non-unique value to a unique/primary key column in your `DataBaseHand.onCreate()` on row 84.

Why it "worked" before was probably because you already had a database. Database helper `onCreate()` is only run once when the database file has just been created from scratch. If you change the database file name, uninstall your app or clear your app's data there won't be a database file so `onCreate()` gets called again and the problems become evident.